# Server Socket Programming can't find file

Tags: python, file-io

In this program I am trying to develop a web server that handles one HTTP request at a time. The web server should accept and parse the HTTP request, get the requested ﬁle from the server’s ﬁle system, create an HTTP response message consisting of the requested ﬁle preceded by header lines, and then send the response directly to the client. If the requested ﬁle is not present in the server, the server should return an HTTP 404 “Not Found” msg.

Here is the code I attempted to make it work:

```
#import socket module
from socket import *
serverPort = 6789
import sys #In order to terminate the program

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

#Prepare a server socket on a particular port
# Fill in code to set up the port
serverSocket.bind(('',serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)

while True:
    # Establish the connection
    print('Ready to serve...')
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept() # Fill in code to get a connection
    try:
        message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)#Fill in code to read GET request
        filename = message.split()[1]
        # Fill in security code
        f = open(filename)
        outputdata = f.read()# Fill in code to read data from the file
        # Send http HEADER LINE (s) into socket
        #Fill in code to send header(s)
        # Send the content of the requested file to the client
        print(outputdata)
        connectionSocket.send('\nHTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n')
        connectionSocket.send(outputdata)
        for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
          connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i].encode())
        connectionSocket.send("\r\n".encode())
        connectionSocket.close()
    except IOError:
        #Send response message for file not found
        #Fill in
        print ("404 Page Not Found")
        connectionSocket.send('\nHTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\n\n')
        #Close client socket
        # Fill in
        connectionSocket.close
serverSocket.close()
sys.exit()
```

Then I try to access a file called HelloWorld.html by typing localhost:6789/HelloWorld.html in a browser address bar to make the program work, but I get this error:

```
Ready to serve...
404 Page Not Found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jcdos/Desktop/CS436/hw2.py", line 21, in <module>
    f = open(filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'/HelloWorld.html'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jcdos/Desktop/CS436/hw2.py", line 37, in <module>
    connectionSocket.send('\nHTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\n\n')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I am getting the 404 not found error, but I the HTML file is in the same directory as my python file. The HelloWorld.html is in the same desktop folder as the python file. In addition, when typing the localhost into the web browser, the browser pops up with this:
[image]

Comment: 'Server socket programming' has exactly nothing to do with 'can't find file'.

Answer (score 0):

If the file exists in the directory then it could be to do with the wrong file name.
I see that in the file name it's checking for `'/HelloWorld.html'` whereas, it should be `'HelloWorld.html'`.

So simply update in your code to exclude the leading forward slash.

```
filename = message.split()[1]
```

To

```
file= message.split()[1]
filename = file[1:]
```